# How do I get a different label for each bar in a bar chart in ChartJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I've been working with ChartJS for the last couple of weeks and I'm getting used to it, however, I'm trying to add individual labels to my bars in my barchart  and I can't figure it out.

Below is the code I'm using.

```
var config = {
    type : 'bar',
    data : {
        datasets : [ {
            label: numberOfFailures, //This line is the problem
            data : failureData,
            backgroundColor : colours,

        } ],
        labels :  labels 
    },
    options : {
        responsive : true,
        legend : {
            position : 'bottom'
        }
    }
};
```

If I change the word label to labels they don't show up at all, but when it says label they all show up together. What I want is for array element 1 to appear on bar 1, etc.

Comment: Could you add a working snippet or a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with a code reproducing the error, or the problem you want us to see. As how you say it, I don't understand what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

If your aim is to take the values from an array and have them appear along the bottom of the bar chart so that each array value is the label for a bar then you need to set the `data.labels` value, not the `data.datasets.label` value.

For example, this basic chart is taken from [the Chart.js documentation for bar chart data structure](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#bar-chart-data-structure) and shows how to use an array of month names to label the bars. Notice that the label bars go into the `data.labels` node.

```js
var data = {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "My First dataset",
            backgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.2)",
            borderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
            borderWidth: 1,
            hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.4)",
            hoverBorderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
            data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
        }
    ]
};
```

If you programmatically create an array with one label for each point of data then it might look something like this:

```js
var chartConfig = {};

for (score = 0; score < maxScore; ++score) {
    chartConfig.scoreLabels[score] = score;
    chartConfig.scoreData[score] = howManyAchievedScore(score);
}

var data = {
    labels: chartConfig.scoreLabels,
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "Number of players who achieved score",
            backgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.2)",
            borderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
            borderWidth: 1,
            hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.4)",
            hoverBorderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
            data: chartConfig.scoreData,
        }
    ]
};
```

You don't have to create the labels and data values inside a single object, but it's usually tidier if you can group your chart configuration data into one object so that you can pass it from one function to another with one parameter.

The `data.datasets.label` value does something different, providing text which appears in the chart legend and in tooltips which appear when you hover over a bar.